# Calling a function-like macro without parentheses?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Suppose that we pass the following to the `gcc`'s preprocessor:

```
#define REM(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define PAIR(x) REM x

PAIR((a)b)
```

It expands `PAIR((a)b)` into `a b`. How does this happen? I am confused about `REM` being used without parentheses and `x` not being echoed as is...

Comment: After replacing `PAIR((a)b)` with `REM (a)b`, the preprocessor goes back to the beginning of the replaced text and rescans it as a sequence of tokens. Pretty obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write:

```
PAIR((a)b)
```

given the definition

```
PAIR(x) REM x
```

that means x = `(a)b`. So, we can write out the right hand side as

```
REM (a)b
```

right?

Now `REM(a)` is just `a`, so `REM (a)b` is just `a b` (tokens are separated by whitespace unless you explicitly use token pasting).